# Singleton Class Keeps 'Losing' UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

I have a Singleton class that I am attempting to use to store an image downloaded from the internet, so I can access it at any time.  The work flow is I log in to Facebook, and it downloads the image to the Singleton class.  Everything is fine, and it displays the image just fine.  However, if I ever quit running the app, the picture is no longer there.  Can someone look at my code and see if I am missing something to get it to always keep the Image?  Like I said before, the first time, it works fine, but if I quit the app, the `UIImage` is just simply not there any more.

**FBSingleton.h**

```
@interface FBSingleton : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *userImage;

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;
@end
```

**FBSingleton.m**

```
@implementation FBSingleton

FBSingleton *sharedInstance = nil;

// Get the shared instance and create it if necessary.

+ (FBSingleton *)sharedInstance {
    @synchronized(self){
        if (sharedInstance == nil) {
            sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
        }
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        // Work your initialising magic here as you normally would

        self.userImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

**ViewController** (In charge of saving the image)

```
NSURL *pictureURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=square&return_ssl_resources=1", facebookID]];

                NSLog(@"Picture URL%@", pictureURL);
                NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pictureURL];

                // Run network request asynchronously
                [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                       completionHandler:
                 ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                     if (connectionError == nil && data != nil) {
                         // Set the image in the header imageView
                         //  self.headerImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                        FBSingleton *sharedSingleton = [FBSingleton sharedInstance];
                         UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                         sharedSingleton.userImage = image;
                     }
                 }];
```

Comment: You mean, that after app reloading, UIImageView is empty ? Or UIImage is empty ? Did you made Save/Load function to disk/cache or you want to make it only online ?

Comment: FYI a better way to do a singleton is with `dispatch_once`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're expecting your image to be saved to disk, but I don't see any code that saves it to disk or loads it from disk. You'll need to write the image out to a file to persist it between application runs; images held in `strong` properties are only held as long as the memory is allocated. When your application quits, the memory is released.

It's hard to say if this is definitely the issue, but based on your description of the problem you're having, it likely is the cause of the "error" that you're seeing. Try using one of:

```
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:cachedNameAbsolutePath atomically:YES];
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:cachedNameAbsolutePath atomically:YES];
```

Then when your app starts, check to see if `cachedNameAbsolutePath` exists and load the image. If it doesn't exist, that's when you'd contact Facebook to download the image again.

Comment: Would I need to put one of those methods in the Singleton class, or in the ViewController class when it downloads it?  I tried putting it there, but cachedNameAbsolutePath gave an error.

Comment: You'll want to execute this where you have downloaded the file; in your case, that would be the ViewController. You'll need to compute your own value for `cachedNameAbsolutePath` as a target filename for your image file. Something like "myCachedImage.png" but as an absolute path.